# Zomato-API behaving weirdly different api calls

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, promise, zomato-api

```
const zomato = require("zomato-api");

const client = zomato({
userKey: "my-user-key",
});

// fetching one data and chaining another fetch

client.getGeocode({lat: lat-value, lon: lon-value}).then(result => {
console.log(result);
// now using the data fetched we get the restaurant details
return client.getRestaurant({res_id: result.popularity.nearby_res[0]})
}).then(res_data => {
console.log(res_data);
});
```

So, the idea was to extract the nearby_res array from the geocode API's result and then use one of the elements (each element is an id) as the parameter for the next API call.

```
client.getRestaurant({res_id: result.popularity.nearby_res[0]})
```

Now, this should originally return all the details about the restaurant with the id specified.

When invoked independently with an id, the `getRestaurant()` function returns the result in the expected format. But when it is chained like this, the result is basically the same as the result of the first API call ( geocode API).

Am I doing anything wrong here? or is the Zomato API reluctant to do this kind of chaining.

Please help.